# Heroku Toolbelt Windows Updater.rb:60 undefined method `[]`

Tags: windows, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Running any Heroku Toolbelt command returns:

```
C:/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:60:in `client_version_from_path`: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from C:/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:170:in 'inject_libpath'
from C:/Heroku/bin/heroku:24:in '<main>'
```

I reinstalled the toolbelt to the root to ensure that the previous path (which had a space) wasn't causing the problem. Searching the internet has found no one with similar problems and the only general recommendations I found were installing the Heroku gem (which is now depricated). Have any ideas I could try?

Alternately, if there is a way to SSH into a Heroku App without the toolbelt, I'd be open to that option as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the suggestion of Heroku support, we removed the `.heroku` folder from the home directory, and then completely uninstalled the Heroku toolbelt before re-installing and then everything began working normally.